# Live streaming of video over internet in android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I am a new bee in android application, here is the brief of my problem, I am creating an application where I need to get video from internet and stream in the device default players.

Note: I don't want to download entire video and play,I need something relevant to live streaming into the default players on the device.

Any idea or way how to start would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Rojesh.

Answer (score 0):

`VideoView` has a method `setVideoPath(path)` where the *path* can be also an HTTP URL.